# Concatenate values of list to create .csv file in r

Tags: r

Let's say i have this `DF`:

```
  Group.1     Abstract      Advisor
1 ANHEMBI     TRUE,FALSE    TRUE
2   BNDES     TRUE,FALSE    FALSE
3    CDTN     TRUE          TRUE
4    CPRM     TRUE          TRUE
5     EBM     TRUE          TRUE
6    ENAP     FALSE         TRUE,FALSE
```

when i try to write the .csv file it returns an error, because some observations are `lists`.

How could i, for example, concatenate those values so it would come like this:

```
  Group.1     Abstract      Advisor
1 ANHEMBI     TRUE|FALSE    TRUE
2   BNDES     TRUE|FALSE    FALSE
3    CDTN     TRUE          TRUE
4    CPRM     TRUE          TRUE
5     EBM     TRUE          TRUE
6    ENAP     FALSE         TRUE|FALSE
```

And i could write the .csv file.

I've done a similar trick in other data, but i only did it for one column, using this code:

```
for(i in 1:length(df[,1])){
  if(is.list(df[i,9])){
    df[i,9]=paste(unlist(df[i,9]),collapse="|")
  }
}
```

How could i do it for all the columns? (my DF has over 20)

And i'd also like to know if this is the best way to export lists into dataframes, or if there are another suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
   mutate_at(2:3, funs(str_replace(., ",", "|")))
```

---

If the columns are `list`

```
library(purrr)
DF %>%
   mutate_at(2:3, funs(map_chr(., ~ paste(.x, collapse="|"))))
```

Comment: Hi there" i've tried the code where the columns are list and i've got this error message: Evaluation error: could not find function "map_chr".

Comment: @LuccaRamalho  Sorry, it should be in `purrr`, updated

Comment: Purrrfect! Thanks a lot =)

Comment: Done! And while you're still here: any suggestions on how to manipulate lists do df? is this really the best way of doing it? where to find this kind of material? thank you

Comment: @LuccaRamalho `lists` are a good way of storing it.  Otherwise for more flexibility, it may be better to `%>% unnest` (if the lengths are the same across the columns) to have a long dataset.  It is based on preference.